# string to replace character only it matches symbols using regex

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would require some suggestion on how to replace/modify strings from the second column of csv by searching a list of symbols matches.

Here is my file.csv

```
[Entry]
Date,20-02-2000
[Input]
SL,Name,Datasize,value
1,tg12.18.l,ch17,12.1
2,yo11`18.p,ch18,13.5
3,qk13_18.q,ch19,22.6
4,ls15-18.r,ch20,23.7
5,ew16'18.s,ch21,24.9
```

After running sed/awk , below is the expected outcome

```
[Entry]
Date,20-02-2000
[Input]
SL,Name,Datasize,value
1,tg12_18_l,ch17,12.1
2,yo11_18_p,ch18,13.5
3,qk13_18_q,ch19,22.6
4,ls15-18_r,ch20,23.7
5,ew16_18_s,ch21,24.9
```

If the search matches `-` and `_` no actions.
If the search matches `,` `<` `` ` `` `'` replace needs to done with a underscore sign: `_`.

I tried with some combinations using `awk` and this is not working.

```bash
 awk -F, -v OFS=, 'sub(/\.\`\>\'/,"_",$2)+1' file.csv
```

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: You said `,` should be replaced but given the file is a *comma-separated*  should not the commas  be ignored? Because in this case a `,` should a indicate a *new column or value*

Comment: @EdgarMagallon yes the comma is matched only second column string, the it will be replaced by _ sign.

Comment: Looks like you also want to replace `.`s with `_`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's{^\d+,\K[^,]+}{$& =~ s/[^\w-]/_/gr}e' -- "$file"
```

Replaces one or more (`+`) characters other than  `,` (`[^,]`) that follows the start of the line (`^`) and one or  more (`+`) `\d`ecimal `\d`igits and a `,` (`\K` to reset the start of the match), with the same (`$&`) where any character other than a `\w`ord character (alnum or underscore) or `-` is replaced with a `_`.

So in effect, we replace characters other than alnum, `_` and `-` in the second field if the first field is entirely made of decimal digits.

To restrict the match to those particular tables in the file, you could make it:

```
perl -pi -e 's{^\d+,\K[^,]+}{$& =~ s/[^\w-]/_/gr}e if
               /^SL,Name/ .. /^\[/' -- "$file"
```

Where we only  make those substitutions in between a line that starts with `SL,Name` and the next line that starts with `[`.

The file is edited in place with `-i`, `-p` is for the `sed` mode where the `-e`xpression is evaluated for each line of the file(s) (with the line stored in `$_`, the default variable `s/pattern/replacement/flags` works on, equivalent to the *pattern space* in `sed`).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i tested but this is not getting my expected outcome. Could you check this with my original file.csv please

Comment: @user183980, my bad, I had missed the fact there was more than one character to replace. See edit.

Comment: Great this works :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Since OP edited the data. It's better to use `awk` now instead of `sed`.

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}/^[0-9]+,/{gsub(/[\.<`\x27]/,"_",$2);print;next}1' file.csv
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i corrected the file.csv file now for the second column. You can see there are two matches coming in the same string on second column and this needs to replaced with _ sign.  I tested this but only looking the first symbol and second symbol ignoring. could you please help.

Comment: @user183980 see edit.

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` inside a bracket expression as it's already literal, you should use `\047` instead of `\x27` to represent a `'` (see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote), and you can remove `;print;next` without changing the output of the script since the `next` after the `print` is just skipping the second `print` caused by `1`. You don't really need to test for leading digits given the OPs sample input either. So, all you really need is ```awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/[.<`\047]/,"_",$2)} 1' file.csv```.

Comment: @EdMorton "You don't really need to test for leading digits given the OPs sample input either."  I think it's safe to have ``/^[0-9]+,/`` because without this, awk may affect these rows, ``Date,20-02-2000``and ``SL,Name,Datasize,value`` if the second field of these rows have any of the characters in ``[.<`\047]``, like for example, ``Date,20.02.2000`` and ``SL,<Name>,Datasize,value``. `<` and `.` would be become  ``_``. I totally agree with the rest of what you pointed out. I didn't know much of them until now.

Comment: You're right about "if the second field..." but, according to the OPs data, they don't. Similarly if we don't assume the rest of the OPs data looks as they posted then the rows that need to change may not all start with digits, maybe some can start with null or `-1` or similar. Maybe the safer test is for `NR>4`, idk, but IMHO it's safe to assume the OPs real data looks like their posted example until if/when they tell us otherwise.

Comment: Perfect i tested this and worked well